# Is there a nontrivial perfect vertex transitive graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Where would one find a nontrivial (i.e. not complete multipartite) graph who is both vertex-transitive and perfect? Is there one?

Edit: Perhaps I should add: apart from even cycles?

Comment: What's wrong with $C_6$?

Comment: ... and not a cycle?

Comment: Perhaps you want to add "vertex-transitive bipartite graphs and their complements" to the list of trivial examples.

Comment: To avoid giving the impression of "moving the goal posts" it would be nice if the OP gave some added context about what motivates the Question.

Comment: Well, I am moving the goalposts. I admit it. In terms of motivation, perfect graphs seem to have structure, as do graphs that have symmetry properties.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask for a classification: We have bipartite graphs and complete multipartite graphs, and graphs generated in various fashions from these (product, complement) that leaves the question what more examples are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example you could take the Cartesian product of two complete graphs - the so called  [rook graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph).

Comment: Okay, thanks. So the next question might consist of: "Is every vertex transitive graph that is perfect generated from even cycles and complete multipartite graphs by complementation and cartesian multiplication?"

Comment: @JohnSmith Not sure. I guess you can always take the line graph of a vertex transitive bipartite graph.